# Create own class wrapper similar to GraphQLList

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

In DB I have data in "set" format. Like '1,2,3...' or 'as_3,dc_4,...'. To clients this data sends as array over graphql.js. I use resolvers for process them. But want made wrap class similar to GraphQLList that I can wrap other data types. Is it possible? And how to do it?

Comment: If the data returned from your database is an array of strings or numbers, the existing `GraphQLList` wrapper type should be sufficient. Can you elaborate why it doesn't meet your use case?

Comment: `GraphQLList` currently work for me. But I need make additional transformation `.join(',')` and `.split(',')` for each field. I want to put this logic on wrapper and make code cleaner from this transformations.